# Unable to extract XML node value from a file in JS - it prints out as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to handle a simple XML file with JS (server-side). So far, with every solution I've tried out, the value shows as "undefined".

I've tried a couple of different approaches, yet I still cannot get past loading the XML file itself and successfully displaying it.
When I've tried to parse it with a DOMParser, the node value is "undefined" (see the present code please).
Another approach I've taken before is to treat it as an XML file without changing it to string beforehand - then I get the '.getElementsByTagName('node')[0]; is not a function' error.

```
function loadXML(postID){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var file = 'logs/queue'+postID+'.xml';

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
console.log('[DEBUG]Readystate: '+this.readyState+', status: '+this.status);
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200) {

myFunction(this);
};

function myFunction(xmlfile) {
var xmlDoc=null;
var data = "";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var user;
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(String(xmlfile), "text/xml");
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("node");

for(i=0; i< nodes.length; i++){
tipper = nodes[i].getAttribute("id");
}
console.log(user) 
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

My only expectation is to obtain the node attribute value of the "node" element.
Instead, I keep getting the "undefined" value as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of struggling with this matter, I finally came up with a working solution.
Therefore, in case somebody was having a problem similar to mine, here goes:

First, I've npm-installed [libxmljs](https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/). From this point, after quickly checking its wiki page, things went almost silky smooth. The modified code can be analyzed below:

```
function loadXML(postID){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var file = 'file.xml';  

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log('[DEBUG]Readystate: '+this.readyState+', status: '+this.status);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200) {

    myFunction(this);
    };

}

        function myFunction(xmlfile) {


            var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xmlfile.responseText);
            var nodes = xmlDoc.root().childNodes();
            var node = nodes[0];
            var node_id = xmlDoc.get('//user').attr('id').value();
            var uname = xmlDoc.get('//name');
            var uamount = xmlDoc.get('//u_amount');
            var umessage = xmlDoc.get('//u_message');
            console.log('[DEBUG] [id=%s] User: %s. Amount: %s. Message: %s.', node_id, uname.text(), uamount.text(), umessage.text() );
            }


xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);

xmlhttp.send();
};
```